# My manager asked me to resign in front of colleagues. Should I resign?

Tags: resignation

I have been working in this organization for more than 3 years and have got 3 performance based awards. I have always worked with dignity and honesty.

Recently there was a lack of clarity in regards to deliverables and while in meeting, in front of my colleagues, my manager asked me to resign. I calmly said "It's your call" and went on to explain the situation. He called me up 20 mins later and apologized.

The Situation is:- Now I don't feel like coming back in to the office. I hear comments from my colleagues which make me feel bad.

Should I resign? or wait for it to pass?

Comment: We cannot tell you what to do. However, your **problem** seems to be the comments of your colleagues, not the actual action your boss apologized for. Maybe you should refocus your question on that and give some examples.

Comment: This is not really the place for such advice on what you should do, but one step I would at least take is ask your boss to publicly apologize, like he did when he "accused" you...

Comment: Just saying: So far you have handled this bad situation in the best possible way. Under no circumstances should you resign - you will lose all your rights if you do that. If you decide you don't want to work there, you can obviously complain to HR about the manager's behaviour.

Comment: Insult in public, apology in private. Wonderful manager.

Answer (score 11):

It's nice that your boss apologized to you privately.

However, it's likely the coworkers who were present in the meeting where he asked you to resign (!) are not at all aware that he backpedaled and apologised to you after the fact.

A public humiliation in front of your peers deserves a public apology or at least an explanation in front of that same group of people, as that is the most effective way to resolve the issue and put any further gossip to rest.

I would request that he address what he said in that unfortunate meeting, publicly, with the group.  The goal is clearing the air and setting the coworkers straight.  You need to make clear that the purpose of your request is not to humiliate *him*, but to stop the comments, which are really bringing you down (understandably I think).

(Since you have not detailed the nature of the comments, I can only presume they seem to be "against" you instead of showing some sympathy for how you were treated. If that is not the case please add additional detail about the nature of these comments to your question)

Answer (score 8):

He asked you to resign and you had a perfect response "It's your call".  Since you are still working then it should be clear his call was to not have you resign. It was just a comment at a meeting - it will pass.